# One database record, two items in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a database query with 1 record as a result which I put in an array. However when I use for each to loop the items it loops two times.

Query as an example is simple:

```
SELECT fieldname FROM tabel WHERE x = y
```

Result:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(36) "some_array_value" ["fieldname"]=> string(36) "some_array_value" }
```

Why does the array have the same value for `both [0]` and `[fieldname]` ? The for each loops both array keys and therefore I get the same result two times. How do I solve this?

Comment: Could you show your code how you actually execute the query and then the loop as well?

Comment: Are you using mysql_fetch_array()?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40796204/when-putting-rows-into-array-it-duplicates

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have used `$result->fetch_array` and you have used the parameter: `MYSQLI_BOTH`, if you want to get rid of the problem you can do:

```
while( $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC) ){
    ...
}
```

Where MYSQLI_ASSOC catches the names..

Comment: Thanks, works fine for me. Didn't know you should use the parameter to only get array names or numbers. Something new learned :)

Comment: If this worked for you please put it as an answer @NML :)

Answer (score 1):

if you take a few seconds to have a glance at the manual, you'll see that your mysql api *by default* returns each datum under both its ordinal position within the select list as well as the column name.

- https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php
- https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php
- https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Answer (score 0):

Please remove mysql_fetch_array with mysql_fetch_assoc OR mysql_fetch_object.
Your problem get resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Using fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC) worked for me :)